# Cannot pass error from controller to view in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I am trying to pass an error from the controller to view to javascript. However, I am not able to capture the error that I am passing from the controller.
Below is the code. When if(signInValid) is false, I am adding error in the model and passing it to the view. But the model is not receiving that error.

```html
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult SignIn(string returnUrl)
        {
            SignInModel model = new SignInModel();
            if (returnUrl != null)
                model.RedirectUrl = returnUrl;
            else
                model.RedirectUrl = "/Home/Index";

            model.AvailableAccounts = _da.GetSystemAccounts();
            return View(model);
        }

 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn(SignInModel model)
 {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (model.ForgotPassword)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    bool signInValid = true; //todo: authenticate

                    Guid userID = _da.VerifyLoginUsername(model.Email);
                    signInValid = _da.VerifyLoginPassword(userID, model.Password);

                    if (signInValid)
                    {
                        return Ok();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        model.Error = "Your e-mail address and password do not match, or the account may have been deactivated";
                    }
                }

            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

Below is the view

```html
@model VeoScheduling.Models.SignInModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "SignIn";
}
<div class="login">
    <h2>Sign In</h2>
    <div>
        <form method="post" asp-action="SignIn" asp-controller="Account">

            <input type="hidden" asp-for="RedirectUrl" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="email"
                       data-bind="value: email" asp-for="Email"
                       class="form-control" id="email-input" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger" id="email-validate"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password"
                       class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="password" asp-for="Password"
                       data-bind="value: password"
                       class="form-control" id="password-input" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger" id="password-validate"></span>
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="Error" class="text-danger" id="login-error"></span>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Account</label>
                <select name="accountSelected" style="margin:5px;width:200px"
                        data-bind='options: availableAccounts, optionsText: "value", optionsValue: "key", value: selectedAccount,event:{change: accountSelected()}'></select>

            </div>

            <br />

            <!--ko if: availableAccounts().length > 0 -->
            <div class="form-group">
                @*<input type="submit" value="Sign In" class="dialogButton" />*@
                <input type="button"
                       data-bind="click: signOn"
                       value="Sign In"
                       class="dialogButton" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <!--/ko-->
            <!--ko if: availableAccounts().length == 0 -->
            <span class="text-danger">Your account does not exist.</span>
            <!--/ko-->

        </form>
    </div>

</div>

@section Scripts{
  
    <script>
            var vModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));
    </script>
    <script src="~/js/signIn.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

Below is a javascript code. I am expecting an error in self.error that I am passing from the controller but it is always empty.

```html
var viewModel = function (model) {
    var self = this;


    //properties
    self.email = ko.observable('');
    self.error = ko.observable(model.error);
    self.password = ko.observable('');
    self.redirectUrl = model.redirectUrl;

    self.availableAccounts = ko.observableArray(model.availableAccounts);
    self.selectedAccount = ko.observable(null);

    //events
    self.signOn = function () {
        console.log("Email : ", self.email());
        console.log("Password : ", self.password());
        console.log("Error : ", self.error());
        if (self.email() == null || self.email() == "") {
            $('#email-validate').html("*Email is required");
            return false;
        }
        if (self.password() == null || self.password() == "") {
            $('#password-validate').html("*Password is required");
            return false;
        }
        if (self.email() != null && self.password != null) {
            var payloadData = {
                'email': self.email(),
                'password': self.password(),
                'accountSelected': self.selectedAccount()
            };

            var url = window.location.origin + '/account/SignIn';

            CallService("Post", url, payloadData)
                .done(function (data) {
                    console.log(self);
                    if (self.error() != null || self.error() != "") {
                        var url = window.location.origin + self.redirectUrl;
                        //window.location.replace(url);
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#login-error").html("*Your e-mail address and password do not match, or the account may have been deactivated");
                    }

                });
        }


    };


    $(document).ready(function () {
        self.vm = new viewModel(self.vModel);
        ko.applyBindings(self.vm);
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you even get the `error` value in your `Model`? I am not sure what you are trying to do here because I do not see you submitting your `form` that you create.

Comment: Why you need to `return View(model);` in your post method? Per my understanding, if you need to check the sign in message, you should return "success" or "fail" to the frontend and then show error message or redirect to home page...